# How to name project with + in the name in XCODE

Tags: iphone, xcode

I need to create a project for an application that I'll call appname+.
Ok the problem is that when I press create project and in the product name i set appname+ in the bundle identifier there is - and not +.

How do I have to call it?

And then how I make it be + when the app is on the device?

Thanks.

Comment: the application's name can be different from the name on the springboard. so, there is no point to add any special char to your project's name. however, the `+` sing **is not allowed** in any class or property or variable or method name.

Comment: Then in the project name I could put Plus instead of + and then in the Application's Name I set +.
Is it right?

Comment: it is absolutely positive. :)